# How to generate maven-jar-plugin 3.1.2 version in pom by swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

Tags: swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I am using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin 2.4.7 version to generate project. it generates maven-jar-plugin 2.6 version, but I need 3.1.2 version.

is there a way to generate custom plugin version?

generated pom.xml:

> ```
>        <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.6</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>jar</goal>
>                         <goal>test-jar</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>             <configuration>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
> ```

wanted pom.xml:

> ```
>        <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.1.2</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>test-jar</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>             <configuration>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
> ```

Comment: What `<language>` value did you use in the Swagger Codegen Maven plugin?

Comment: <language>java</language>
<library>jersey2</library>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swagger Codegen's output is based on Mustache templates. For example, the `pom.xml` template for the Java client + `jersey2` library is available here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/jersey2/pom.mustache

Swagger Codegen lets you override the built-in templates with custom templates. You can do this as follows:

1. Create a folder (say, `codegen-templates`) in your project.
2. Download the `pom.mustache` template from this link to that folder.
   https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/jersey2/pom.mustache
3. Edit the downloaded `pom.mustache` and update the `maven-jar-plugin` version and configuration as required.
4. In your `pom.xml`, specify the path to the `codegen-templates` folder in the `<templateDirectory>` parameter:

   ```xml
   <plugin>
       <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
       <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.7</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <goals>
                   <goal>generate</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <inputSpec>https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                   <language>java</language>
                   <library>jersey2</library>

                   <!-- The folder containing your custom pom.mustache -->
                   <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/codegen-templates</templateDirectory>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

Now Swagger Codegen will generate `pom.xml` based on your custom `pom.mustache` template.

Comment: Great! Please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/131247) to mark it as the solution to your question.